# Checking folder with Dir.glob and writing the images to the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rufus-scheduler

I'm currently scanning a specific folder and write the images from that folder to my model (for this i'm using rufus-scheduler as a background-job).
Now that works perfectly it just does one thing slighty wrong.

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'
scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler::singleton

scheduler.in '5s' do
  Image.new
  @images = Dir.glob("app/assets/images/*.jpg")
  @images.each do |image|
    Image.create(file: @images)
  end
end
```

So 5 seconds after my server strats it writes all the .JPG files from the assets folder to my model. It makes seperate ID's aswell wich i wanted but it litterly puts all the images in 1 ID instead of writing 1 image to each ID.

```
<Image id: 54, created_at: "2015-12-30 21:30:24", updated_at: "2015-12-30 21:30:24", file: "[\"app/assets/images/Cup-1.jpg\", \"app/assets/images...">
```

Image model attributes:

```
Image(id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, file:string)
```

Next to that, i'd like to wish everyone already a happy new year!

Comment: Please flag Adam's answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you are enumerating `@images` and creating a model for each one but saving the array `@images` to the `file` attribute. The correct line should be `Image.create(file: image)` or `Image.find_or_create_by(file: image)`